# InvalidOperationException during deserialize

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization

Sorry, if i made a mistake but am new to serialization.
Following piece of code throws the invalid operation exception when deserializing the string XML:

```
private static void getData<T>(T objectcust, string customizationXML) where T : class
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    using (TextReader reader = new StringReader(customizationXML))
    {
        objectcust = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

So, i want to write a generic method that performs deserialization.

Here is the string XML that i got upon serialization:

```
"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n<PerfStatusCustomization xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\">\r\n  <ClsSchemeID>101</ClsSchemeID>\r\n</PerfStatusCustomization>"
```

here is the exception detail:

```
Message: There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
Exception Type: System.InvalidOperationException
Source: System.Xml
18: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
17: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(TextReader textReader)
```

AND, this is how i'm calling this generic method:

```
 public static object DeserializedCustomizationXml(string customizationXML, AssessmentsCustomizations assessmentsCustomizations)
 {
            object objectname = null;
            switch (assessmentsCustomizations)
            {
          case AssessmentsCustomizations.PerformanceStatus:
                    objectname = new PerfStatusCustomization();
                     break;
         }
       
     getData(objectname, customizationXML);
            return objectname;
  }
```

Comment: Please add Exception message (and stacktrace) as text to your question.

Comment: added exception details

Comment: it doesn't throw any exception for `public class PerfStatusCustomization
{
 public int ClsSchemeID { get; set;}
}` [chek this out](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YS6Ysg)

Comment: I second Selvin: Seems your code is ok. Your input is flawed.

Comment: Please see how i'm calling this generic method

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate and I've tried to find the best existing answer to target. But if that's not the one you need, Google "There is an error in XML document (2, 2)." There are a number of answers.

Comment: _"Please see how i'm calling this generic method"_ - yes, that's flawed, too. You should `return objectcust` from `getData`. Setting the param variable like that is useless because it goes out of scope. But the exception is still a different issue.

Comment: Ah, wait a second ... I have a suspicion ... could you try according the code from this fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/zXkeHQ